# Edit suggestion was approved although it was rejected by a user

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

[This edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/856069) was approved although it was rejected by a user, and no other votes were cast.

According to [suggested edits FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work):

> Three accept or reject votes are required to approve/reject an edit.

So, what caused this edit to be approved?

Comment: Bad question, even worse edit suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fixed now. We recently introduced a bug in which if the question *asker* with <2k reputation approved a suggested edit, then the "approve" review wasn't correctly recorded.

In other words, if it weren't for this bug, this suggested edit would show

> [David Liu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1764269/david-liu) reviewed this [some time ago]: **Approve**

We'll try to get the bad data cleaned up.