# Suggested edit approved with 0 approvals and 1 rejection

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

I reviewed [this SO suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2328793) some days ago. After I rejected it, something similar to [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/856069) (documented in [this Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152143/edit-suggestion-was-approved-although-it-was-rejected-by-a-user)) happened:

> **Approved** Jun 17 at 11:07:
>
> michaelb958 reviewed this Jun 17 at 11:06: **Reject**
>   This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.

And that's all there was.

Viewing [the post's revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17145998/revisions) indicates the edit *was* actually approved. The Meta question I linked to dates from 2012, and indicates that whatever bug was responsible was fixed. (Also, that was a question, whereas this is an answer.) What's going on here?

---

**Edit:** [This bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195576/223030) provides a possible explanation - at time of writing, if the OP approves an edit after running out of suggested edit reviews, it doesn't show up on the edit's summary.

Comment: The second suggested edit you link to was approved by the post owner (different background colour to the username). This didn't appear to happen in your example.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Maybe it did; I can't tell, because the suggested-edit page isn't showing me.

Comment: @michaelb958: Because OP approved it.

Comment: @Mr.ØØ7 But the suggested edit page *should* show you if the OP approved it, that it doesn't would be a bug, not intended behavior.

Comment: Darn it @9Shogs, you come to mark your question as a dupe and some staffer's already done it...