# Reviewing suggested edit of own post after completing 20 reviews

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, rate-limiting

I've completed 20 suggested edits reviews today. Then, I came across a [suggested edit to my own post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2846043) and I approved it.

Then, I had a doubt that whether the review count has incremented or not, oh! it's not incrementing. System works fine.

But, take a look at review page,

[image]

The edit was already reviewed by one reviewer and then I reviewed it. As I'm the Owner of the post it's enough to approve the edit. But, the review history doesn't show the detail that I had approved it. It's misleading that only one vote of a reviewer who is neither the community user nor the OP nor the moderator, is enough.

So, what should we do in this type of situation?

Is it correct to make OP to review the suggested edit after completing daily limit?

Should we need to display/hide the OP has approved the edit in the review history?

Comment: BTW what is rare-limiting?

Comment: @hims056, corrected spelling.

Comment: That's a display bug, which also explains some weird behaviors I saw recently. Cheers for spotting this!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately this was not a display bug but, but a real bug dating way back. After exceeding the review queue limit the suggested edit was still approved, but not recorded in the review history. I guess it's a consequence of the suggested edits being there before the review queues.

As of build rev `2014.1.9.1838` on meta and `2014.1.9.1289` on sites, this should be working correctly (for new reviews only).