# How can this user review more than 20 edits per day?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, rate-limiting, review-stats

Today, in the [suggested edits review stats](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats),

[image]

How is this possible?

[He](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1397504/nico) is not even a [moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189302/is-it-possible-for-moderators-to-review-more-than-the-daily-limited-count).

Comment: Guess: Someone proposed an edit to his own post and he reviewed it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, then it will be a bug.

Comment: @Azik no, not a bug.

Comment: @Azik: Why would that be? I am wrong in this case, however.

Comment: His last suggested edit review was on [his own post](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3865139). It's by design. Bonus: I hate non free hand circles.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: No, this is **not** a duplicate of that post; this is about reviews on your own posts instead. That specific bug, as you pointed out, has been fixed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - He has not voted to close a bug report he linked in your answer. See [the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158342/187824) on a possible duplicate question. :-)

Comment: @hims056: okay, fair enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He [reviewed a suggested edit on his own post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3865139). Note that his name is highlighted in blue on the reviewers roll call:

[image]

If you look over [his review history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1397504/nico?tab=activity&sort=reviews) you'll see that this was his 21st suggested edit review today.

The OP is always given a veto vote on suggested edits on his own posts, regardless of review queue limits.

Comment: Not sure that's the case, in my opinion it's more likely a deleted post.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: this is his most recent suggested edit review.

Comment: True, [there was a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195576/152859), fixed only 12 days ago. Before the bug fix, that review wouldn't have counted and the suggested edit page would have shown empty as in the bug report.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: There are 20 other suggested edits in his history since midnight UTC. This is review 21, on his own post. This is **not** about deleted posts (which we would not see in his history).

Comment: But when I [reviewed my own post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195576/reviewing-suggested-edit-of-own-post-after-completing-20-reviews) after daily limit the count was not incremented.

Comment: @Azik: which was a bug, now fixed. :-)

Comment: And today 22 :D

Comment: @Azik: yup, the last two are again reviews on his own posts.

Comment: can you tell me why this [user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1799355/digvesh-patel) has reviewed more than 20 edits today?

Comment: @Azik: Again, reviews on your own posts don't count against the limit. See http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3942444 for the one extra post, it's on his own answer.

Comment: But, that's not his 21st review.

Comment: @Azik: No, but reviews on your own posts *don't count* against the quota. It doesn't matter if that review is the first, somewhere in the middle or the last, he still gets to review 20 suggested edits in a day that are not on his own posts.

Comment: Could you please provide me the link where it is mentioned?

Comment: Why would it work any other way? Reviews on your own edits don't count as reviews, because you usually find those *in your inbox*, not in the review queue.

Comment: yeah, I can't found them on review queue, but I don't understand `reviews on your own edits don't count as reviews` but can be added to review count.

Comment: @Azik: They count as reviews, they just don't count against your review *quota*.